# How to add quil lein template to windows

Tags: clojure, leiningen, quil

I want to start using quil to write some creative art but im having troube installing the template. I manage to install the leiningen successfuly, i can run lein -help and it works, but when i try

```
lein new quil my-sketch
```

i get this error

```
lein new quill my-art
Failed to resolve version for quill:lein-template:jar:RELEASE: Could not find metadata quill:lein-template/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\danie\.m2\repository)
Failed to read artifact descriptor for quill:lein-template:jar:RELEASE
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
Could not find template quill on the classpath.
```

what im missing? i found out that there is a github repo called quill-templates, but i dont understand what im suppouse to download or add to path to make this work, im running it on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

It's just a little typo, `quil` is spelled with only one `l`:

```
lein new quil my-art
```